# ANTLR4 : problems with parsing symbols like minus and dot in both numbers and strings

Tags: regex, parsing, antlr4, symbols, lexer

I'm using ANTLR4 and trying to parse '.' in both strings and numbers. I have the 2 following statements I want to be able to parse, of which I can only successfully parse one or the other, but not both:

```
str = "sentence. more.";
num = 5.5;
```

I'm using the following grammar file:

```
grammar TestGrammar;

// Parser rules
rule : statement*;

statement : assignmentStatement;

assignmentStatement : identifier '=' numberLiteral ';' 
                    | identifier '=' stringLiteral ';'
                    ;

numberLiteral : MINUS? NUM* DOT? NUM+;
stringLiteral : '"' string '"';

string : (SYMBOL | CHAR | NUM)+;
identifier : UNDERSCORE? (CHAR | NUM)+;

// Lexer rules

WS : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ -> skip;

CHAR : [a-zA-Z];
NUM : [0-9];
SYMBOL : [<>#=&|!(){}.\-:;];

MINUS : '-';
UNDERSCORE : '_';
DOT : '.';
```

There is overlap between the DOT and SYMBOL lexer rules. Currently, it is able to parse the string but not the number. If I change the rule order so that DOT is before SYMBOL, it can then parse the number but not the string.

I tried directly using '.'? in the numberLiteral rule and removing DOT rule, which still caused problems when matching strings. I've also tried changing the SYMBOL rule to something like the following:

```
SYMBOL : [<>#=&|!(){}DOT\-:;];
```

Maybe I have the syntax wrong but that cannot parse the string correctly. How can I change my grammar file so that it can successfully parse both? I was having similar problems with MINUS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to create Number and String Literals as tokens (if you want to name the sub-parts, you can use fragments, but understand that you'll only get `STRING` or `NUMBER` tokens. There are not tokens generated for fragment matching and tokens do not have tokens as components, they are leaf nodes on the parse tree.

Try this:

```
grammar TestGrammar
    ;

// Parser rules
rule: statement*;

statement: assignmentStatement;

assignmentStatement
    : IDENTIFIER '=' NUMBER ';'
    | IDENTIFIER '=' STRING ';'
    ;

NUMBER: MINUS? NUM* DOT? NUM+;
STRING: '"' (SYMBOL | CHAR | NUM | SPACE)+ '"';

//string: (SYMBOL | CHAR | NUM)+;

// Lexer rules
IDENTIFIER: UNDERSCORE? (CHAR | NUM)+;

fragment CHAR:   [a-zA-Z];
fragment NUM:    [0-9];
fragment SYMBOL: [<>#=&|!(){}.\-:;];
fragment SPACE: ' ';

fragment MINUS:      '-';
fragment UNDERSCORE: '_';
fragment DOT:        '.';

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

Comment: That worked great thanks! I don't quite understand the difference between parsing and lexer tokens, and how making string and number lexer rules changes the behaviour, but really appreciate the help!

Comment: Yeah, you'll really want to get that distinction down or you'll be contstantly frustrated.  The (too short) answer is that the Lexer processes the stream of characters and creates a stream of tokens (using Lexer rules), then (and only then), parser rules act on the stream of Tokens.  parser rules have no influence on Lexer rules.  The _Definitive ANTLR4 Reference_ is very accessible and well worth the time and cost.

Answer (score 0):

A number is discrete, so appropriate to match in the lexer. `Dot`s not consumed in a number will be emitted as `DOT`s.

```
DOUBLE  : [+-]? DecimalFloatingPoint ;
DOT     : Dot ;

fragment DecimalFloatingPoint
    : DecDigits Dot DecDigits? ExponentPart? FloatSuffix?
    | Dot DecDigits ExponentPart? FloatSuffix?
    | DecDigits ExponentPart FloatSuffix?
    | DecDigits FloatSuffix
    ;

fragment ExponentPart  : [eE] [+-]? DecDigits ;
fragment FloatSuffix   : [fFdD] ;
fragment DecDigits     : [0-9]+ ;
fragment Dot           : '.' ;
```

PS: the [Antlr Grammars Repo](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4) is a good place to look for examples.

Comment: Thanks! What's the difference between discrete and continuous in the context of grammar rules?

Comment: Nominally, a number is a unified thing suitable for `discrete` tokenization -  any dot or text within a number is purely specific to the number.  So, not `discrete` vs `continuous`, but `discretely tokenizable` vs `syntactic or semantic construct`.